# Input pattern matching

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

Seem's like a trivial question, but how do you test if the key you're about to input, could potentially fulfil the regex pattern.

For instance, I have a string that comes from server like `AAA`, which I loop over per char, and have a map object that looks something like:

```
{
    '9': /\d/,
    'A': /[a-zA-Z]/,
    '*': /[a-zA-Z0-9]/
}
```

Then I construct a regex from that `AAA` to, `/^([a-zA-Z])?([a-zA-Z])?([a-zA-Z])?$/`.. The reason the for optional flag, was to "fulfil" at any char, but no more than 3 chars.

Anyway, so on my `keypress` event I have this code:

```
function(e) {
    var val = e.target.value,
        thisPress = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode),
        potential = val + thisPress;

    if (!potential.match(mask)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

> Where `mask` is that regex (`/^([a-zA-Z])?([a-zA-Z])?([a-zA-Z])?$/`).

Which works, but that'll also fulfil, `a`, or `ab`, or `abc`, rather than being fully fulfilled once `abc` is entered. Would it be, just to wrap a couple more groups on there, maybe do string length matching or what..

Bear in mind, a potential combination would be like `AA-AA_99`, which would translate to `/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]\-[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]\_[0-9][0-9]$/`..

I know these regex statements aren't at all optimised, but it gives the ability for the users using the software to use it, without knowing regex. Even though its primitive.

Hope it all made sense.

Comment: You can't use the same regex for both live validation (masking) and final input validation. Create 2 regexps: one that you have and another without `?` modifier for final validation.

Comment: @stribizhev - Ahh right, interesting.. So what you're saying is a "this regex could fulfill at any point" then once that is fulfilled and it fulfills the final regex, then green light"

Comment: Enforcing what @stribizhev said, I can't figure out why you'd want the regex to fulfill only when complete: I seem it has no sense _in the context of your `keypress` event_, so the final validation must necessarily exist elsewhere.

Comment: @cFreed - Yeah I have a keydown event for the `enter` key, that "commits" that field, and its there that I match the final validation.. The `keypress` event just checks if the key they're about to enter, can potentially match, hence the `?` and not the `?`.

Comment: I prepared me to merely say: "So you agree you don't need your regex to be nothing else that it already is". But I realize that you'd like to be using the same unique regex for the 2 events.

Comment: I will put it so: use `var mask = /^([a-zA-Z])?([a-zA-Z])?([a-zA-Z])?$/;` to vlaidate live input, and `var final = /^([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z])$/;` to validate final input. There is no choice here - it is just how regex works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't use the same regex for both live validation (masking) and final input validation**. Create 2 regexps: one that you have and another without `?` modifier for final validation.

Use

```
var mask = /^([a-zA-Z])?([a-zA-Z])?([a-zA-Z])?$/;
```

to validate live input, and

```
var final = /^([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z])$/;
```

to validate final input.